Override Cookie constructor in laravel 5.5 to allow rendering site inside an iFrame
Laravel 5.5 will only accept lax, strict or null as sameSite options when setting a cookie and will throw and exception if it is not one of these - before you ask I am stuck with laravel 5.5 for now.
To allow the site to render in an iFrame the cookie needs to be set to SameSite: none
Changing the code in vendor does work, but is not a solution, so I looked at extending the Cookie code and using my own constructor.
I found this ticket:
Laravel 5.5 Override vendor class
but the code I would like to change is in Symfony: vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Cookie.php and there is a CookieServiceProvider in Illuminate with is returning an instance of CookieJar which I can see creates a new instance of the symfony cookie in its make() method
Is there a way to extend the symfony code so that laravel uses my version of the constructor?

Not sure about the Laravel/Symfony part of the question - but perhaps letting the web server simply manipulate the resulting Set-Cookie header afterwards might be an option? On Apache that should be possible using https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header

An idea: create your own version of the Cookie class, put it somewhere, and include it early enough (so that the standard class is not autoloaded yet).
